# Regex help (between characters)

Tags: regex

I need a regex which finds the text between `{` and `}`, but inside the found text there cannot by either `{` or `{`.

Example:

```
we have: {hi {Mary Jane} lol}
```

and it should give my only

```
{Mary Jane}
```

Comment: What regex have you tried so far to get {Mary Jane}?

Comment: +1 Welcome to SO!  Don't be discouraged by the downvotes.  Next time, include what you have already tried in your question.  See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the regular expression `{[^{}]*}`:

```
$ echo "{hi {Mary Jane} lol}" | grep -o "{[^{}]*}"
{Mary Jane}
```

This works using the negated character class `[^{}]`, which means "match any character except `{` or `}`.

Comment: @Dawid This `[^{}]` is called a "negated character class" btw.

Comment: Oops, I'll add an explanation to the answer.